# How to make this regular expression Pattern case insensitive - for list of words

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, case-insensitive

How to make this regular expression Pattern case insensitive ^(?!.*PO BOX|P.O BOX).*$

```
<ValidationRule Type="RegEx" RegEx="(?i:^(?!.*PO BOX|P.O BOX).*$)" ErrorMessage="Home Address May not be a P.O. Box. Please enter a physical address as a home address." />
```

Comment: The safest: `RegEx="^(?!.*[Pp][Oo] [Bb][oO][xX]|[pP][.][oO] [Bb][Oo][Xx]).*$"`.

Comment: Thank you  "Stribizhev", "Serv" & "vks"